# Sub_grouped data in vbar plot SAS

Tags: plot, charts, sas

I'm trying to get a vbar chart as this one [image]

But what I get is this: 
[image] .

My dataset stars_freq_T looks like this:
[image]

My current code is:

```
proc gchart data=stars_freq_T;
format col1 percent10.;
vbar stars / discrete sumvar=col1
    subgroup=_NAME_
    raxis = axis1 maxis = axis2
    autoref clipref cref=graydd
    coutline=grayee space=0;
    axis1 label=none order=(-1 to 1 by .2) style=1
    major=none minor=none
    value=(t=1 '100%' t=2 '80%' t=3 '60%' t=4 '40%' t=5 '20%' t=6 '0%');
    axis2 label = ('Review score') style = 0;
    title1 ls=1.5 "Review Distribution";

    pattern1 v=s c=cxb2df8a;
    pattern2 v=s c=cxfdbf6f;
run;
```

Does anyone know what the problem is?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Don't use GCHART either, consider switching to SGPLOT, it creates much better quality graphics, more options for customization, it's easier to use and Graphing procs aren't commonly used anymore.

Comment: Yep.  HIGHLOW plots are much more user friendly here.

Answer (score 0):

Stupid. I forgot to make my "Lower" percentages negative.